# How to debug WiFi errors on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, debug

Is there any way to get an error code from failed wireless connection attempts on Windows?

Just having "Windows can't connect" doesn't help me debug my issue at all. Ideally, getting an error code or some reason of WHY it can't connect would be perfect.

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Windows has built in network diagnostics, have you run it? Right click on the network icon in the system tray and select "Troubleshoot problems"

Comment: @Moab Yes, but I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/aU3FjAg.png). No, it's not my adapter, as my phone and my other laptop connect perfectly to the network.

Comment: Did you click "view detailed information" ?

Comment: @Moab yeah, I end up on the "explore additional options" which just either makes me check Windows help or ask for remote assistance...

Comment: What does the detailed information say exactly?

Comment: with Win 8.1 I would have the same question